# dumping or printing the name of a variable

Tags: java, reflection

This question mentions xpaths but it is really not specific to xpaths and really concerns any Java Strings.

I am using Java 8 and have about 40 Strings (public static final String in the class).  An example is below:

```
private static final String employeeID_x = "//input[@id = 'id']";
private static final String employeeName = "//input[@id = 'EmployeeName']";
```

and there are some more complicated ones like

```
private static final String age_x = "//div[@id = 'Employee']/div[2]/span[1]";
```

etc.  There are 40 of these.  I want to verify all the xpaths so I made an array like

```
private static final String[] arr = {employeeID_x, employeeName_x, age_x, .....};
```

then to verify

```
for (String xp: arr) {
    List<WebElement> eles = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp));
    if (eles.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println(xp + " does not exist");
    }
 }
```

you get the idea.  This works, but the error message is 
"//div[@id = 'Employee']/div[2]/span[1] does not exist".  I guess this is ok but I would rather have it say "age_x does not exist".

I don't know how to print the variable name.  I have tried using Class and getFields() but that does not seem to work.

What I have to do is duplicate the array and put each element in quotes like this:

```
private static final String[] names= {"employeeID_x", "employeeName_x", "age_x", .....};
```

and then get the number of entries and use

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String xp = arr[i];
    String name = names[i];
    List<WebElement> eles = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xp));
    if (eles.size() == 0) {
         System.out.println(name + " does not exist");
    }
}
```

but as you can see this can get to be a pain.  Is there anyway to get the name from xp?  Maybe no, as I am afraid when it creates the array it substitutes the value of each string?

And as you can see, this is not specific to xpaths.

Comment: Instead of a list, store them in a `Map<String, String>` where the key is the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to print the variable name.

With your current array, you *can't* (reasonably*) unless you can infer the variable name from the string. This line:

```
private static final String[] arr = {employeeID_x, employeeName_x, age_x, .....};
```

...copies the **value** of `employeeID_x`, etc., into the array. There is no ongoing link between that value and the variable it came from, just as in this code:

```
a = b;
```

...there is no ongoing link between `a` and `b`.

Your parallel arrays solution works but as you've said isn't ideal. Using  a `Map` may be slightly better:

```
private static final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
    map.put("employeeID_x", employeeID_x);
    map.put("employeeName_x", "employeeName_x);
    // ...
}
```

Then loop through the map's entries, which give you both the name and value. This still has some repetition (e.g., in each `put` call you have to type the variable name twice), but it's much better from a maintenance perspective: Dramatically harder to get the two out of sync.

Another option is to use reflection: Your array would be of the names of the variables, and then you'd get the variable's value by using [`Class#getDeclaredField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) to get a `Field` instance for it, then get the value via [`Field#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-). E.g., your array would be:

```
private static final String[] arr = new String[] { "employeeID_x", "employeeName" /*, ...*/ };
```

...then:

```
for (String name : names) {
    Field f = YourClass.class.getDeclaredField(name);
    String value = (String)f.get(null);
    // ...test `value` here, report `name` if there's a problem
}
```

---

* "reasonably" - You could have the error code compare the string to every one of your fields and report the match, e.g.

```
if (theString.equals(employeeID_x)) {
    theVariableName = "employeeID_x";
} else if (theString.equals(employeeName_x)) {
    theVariableName = "employeeName_x";
} else if (...) {
    // ...
```

...but...blech. :-) (And it assumes that two of these never have the same value.)

Comment: blech yeah ;-)  I think the map is the best way